# PHP begin <p> element from text only

Tags: php, preg-replace, facebook-instant-articles

Am currently working of **facebook instant article** for my website but the in-post images are not showing because the `<figure>` element representing the image must be included standalone within the body of the article and not enclosed within a `<p>` element.

```
$message="[img]http://img.loadedcamp.net/hfjfjd.jpg[/img]

This is the news and it is here.

[img]http://img.loadedcamp.net/YTgxbj.jpg[/img]

The new is posted by an author";
```

This is nl2p() function

```
function nl2p($string, $only_if_no_html = FALSE) {
$replace = TRUE;
if ($only_if_no_html) {
$str2 = strip_tags($string);
if ($str2 != $string) {
  $replace = FALSE;
}
}
if ($replace) {
 return
  '<p>'
  .preg_replace('#(<br\s*?/?>\s*?){2,}#', '</p>'."\n".'<p>', nl2br($string))
  .'</p>';
   }
}
```

This image bbcode changer;

```
function savedimg($string) {
$string = preg_replace("#\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]#is", '<figure> <img src="$1"/> </figure>', $string);
return $string;
}
```

`echo nl2p(savedimg($message));` outputted this;

```
<p><figure> <img src="http://img.loadedcamp.net/hfjfjd.jpg" /> </figure></p>
<p>This is the news and it is here.</p>
<p><figure> <img src="http://img.loadedcamp.net/YTgxbj.jpg" /> </figure></p>
<p>The new is posted by an author</p>
```

I want the `p` element not to be in-between the images. Please help guys!

This is what i expected as output;

```
<figure> <img src="http://img.loadedcamp.net/hfjfjd.jpg" /> </figure>
<p>This is the news and it is here.</p>
<figure> <img src="http://img.loadedcamp.net/YTgxbj.jpg" /> </figure>
<p>The new is posted by an author</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regex pattern in your `savedimg` function to the following:

```
...
$string = preg_replace("#(<p>\s*?)?\[img\](.*?)\[/img\](\s*?</p>)?#is", '<figure> <img src="$2"/> </figure>', $string );
...
```